# Sorting a table in xsl after creation

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to create a HTML table from two node sets in my XML and then sort it by `@AD`.

I can sort within individual for-each loops using `<xsl:sort select="@AD" order="ascending" />`, but I want to sort the whole table.

```
<xsl:template match="*/Sync/AP">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>AD</th>
            <th>GCD</th>
            <th>ClearAttribute</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="./*">
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="@AD"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="@GCD"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="@ClearAttribute"/></td>
        </tr>       
        </xsl:for-each>
        <!-- Also Append the Common attributes to each region -->
        <xsl:for-each select="../Common/*">
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="@AD"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="@GCD"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="@ClearAttribute"/></td>
        </tr>       
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Can you show a sample of your XML, and also the (sorted) output that you expect? Thank you!

Comment: thanks for checking Tim, but Tomalak has given me the info I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't make two separate `<xsl:for-each>`. Select all the nodes you want to display and sort them in one step.

The union operator `|` is used for this:

```
<xsl:template match="Sync/AP">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>AD</th>
            <th>GCD</th>
            <th>ClearAttribute</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="./* | ../Common/*">
            <xsl:sort select="@AD" order="ascending" />
            <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="@AD"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="@GCD"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="@ClearAttribute"/></td>
            </tr>       
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>
```

---

Note: Even though `match` expressions look like XPath, they are not really XPath. This is unnecessary:

```
<xsl:template match="*/Sync/AP">
```

you can use this instead:

```
<xsl:template match="Sync/AP">
```

or even this:

```
<xsl:template match="AP">
```

unless you *explicitly* want to make sure that only `<AP>` with a `<Sync>` parent are matched.

Comment: That was what I was missing. Thanks @Tomalak