# Sorting data from two for-each calls in XSLT

Tags: xslt-1.0

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43631153/sorting-a-table-in-xsl-after-creation) where in the answer it suggests using a union but I can't see how I can do that.

In my situation I am reading data in from two external XML files. The first one contains publishers and the second one contains history. Right now I am sorting by name. The script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msa="http://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/msa">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" version="4.01"
    doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
    doctype-public="//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Publishers Report</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Custom Publisher Report.css"/>
      </head>
      <body>
        <xsl:variable name="PubDB" select="document('MSA_PublisherDatabase.XML')"/>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <th class="cellHeading">Student</th>
            <th class="cellHeading">Last As Student</th>
            <th class="cellHeading">Last Bible Reading</th>
            <th class="cellHeading">Last As Publisher</th>
            <th class="cellHeading">Last As Talk</th>
            <th class="cellHeading">Last As Assistant</th>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$PubDB/msa:PublisherDatabase/msa:Publishers/msa:Publisher">
              <xsl:sort select="msa:Name" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="msa:Publisher">
    <xsl:variable name="HistoryDB" select="document('AssignHistory.XML')"/>
    <xsl:variable name ="SearchName" select="msa:Name"/>
    <tr>
      <!--The first cell is the name-->
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="msa:Name"/>
      </td>
      <!--The next cell is the most recent Student date-->
      <!--So we need to locate all "Bible Reading" items for the name in question-->
      <!--We sort the entries in date descending order so that the first entry is the most recent-->
      <td>
        <xsl:for-each select="$HistoryDB/AssignmentHistory/*/StudentItems/Item[Description != 'Assistant' and Name = $SearchName]">
          <xsl:sort select="$HistoryDB/AssignmentHistory/*" order="descending" data-type="text"/>
          <!--We only want the first entry-->
          <xsl:if test="position()=1">
            <xsl:call-template name="DisplayItemDate">
              <xsl:with-param name="ItemDate" select="name(../..)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <!--If no entries were found then it need to write out "<xsl:text> </xsl:text>" How?-->
      </td>
      <!--The next cell is the most recent Bible Reading date-->
      <!--So we need to locate all "Bible Reading" items for the name in question-->
      <!--We sort the entries in date descending order so that the first entry is the most recent-->
      <td>
        <xsl:for-each select="$HistoryDB/AssignmentHistory/*/StudentItems/Item[Description = 'Bible Reading' and Name = $SearchName]">
          <xsl:sort select="$HistoryDB/AssignmentHistory/*" order="descending" data-type="text"/>
          <!--We only want the first entry-->
          <xsl:if test="position()=1">
            <xsl:call-template name="DisplayItemDate">
              <xsl:with-param name="ItemDate" select="name(../..)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <!--If no entries were found then it need to write out "<xsl:text> </xsl:text>" How?-->
      </td>
      <!--The next cell is the most recent Publisher date-->
      <!--So we need to locate all "Bible Reading" items for the name in question-->
      <!--We sort the entries in date descending order so that the first entry is the most recent-->
      <td>
        <xsl:for-each select="$HistoryDB/AssignmentHistory/*/StudentItems/Item[Description != 'Talk' and Description != 'Assistant' and Name = $SearchName]">
          <xsl:sort select="$HistoryDB/AssignmentHistory/*" order="descending" data-type="text"/>
          <!--We only want the first entry-->
          <xsl:if test="position()=1">
            <xsl:call-template name="DisplayItemDate">
              <xsl:with-param name="ItemDate" select="name(../..)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <!--If no entries were found then it need to write out "<xsl:text> </xsl:text>" How?-->
      </td>
      <!--The next cell is the most recent Talk date-->
      <!--So we need to locate all "Bible Reading" items for the name in question-->
      <!--We sort the entries in date descending order so that the first entry is the most recent-->
      <td>
        <xsl:for-each select="$HistoryDB/AssignmentHistory/*/StudentItems/Item[Description = 'Talk' and Name = $SearchName]">
          <xsl:sort select="$HistoryDB/AssignmentHistory/*" order="descending" data-type="text"/>
          <!--We only want the first entry-->
          <xsl:if test="position()=1">
            <xsl:call-template name="DisplayItemDate">
              <xsl:with-param name="ItemDate" select="name(../..)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <!--If no entries were found then it need to write out "<xsl:text> </xsl:text>" How?-->
      </td>
      <!--The last cell is the most recent Assistant date-->
      <!--So we need to locate all "Bible Reading" items for the name in question-->
      <!--We sort the entries in date descending order so that the first entry is the most recent-->
      <td>
        <xsl:for-each select="$HistoryDB/AssignmentHistory/*/StudentItems/Item[Type = 'Assistant' and Name = $SearchName]">
          <xsl:sort select="$HistoryDB/AssignmentHistory/*" order="descending" data-type="text"/>
          <!--We only want the first entry-->
          <xsl:if test="position()=1">
            <xsl:call-template name="DisplayItemDate">
              <xsl:with-param name="ItemDate" select="name(../..)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <!--If no entries were found then it need to write out "<xsl:text> </xsl:text>" How?-->
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="DisplayItemDate">
    <xsl:param name="ItemDate"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring($ItemDate, 8, 2)"/>
    <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring($ItemDate, 6, 2)"/>
    <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring($ItemDate, 2, 4)"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As you can see my table has several columns. Is it possible to sort this data on any of the other columns instead?

I thought the other question would have the answer ....

I hope I make sense and I thank you for your time.

## Update

I tried to add some javascript to allow the user to click on the column headings instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msa="http://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/msa">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" version="4.01"
    doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
    doctype-public="//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Publishers Report</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Custom Publisher Report.css"/>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11"/>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="https://rawgithub.com/padolsey/jQuery-Plugins/master/sortElements/jquery.sortElements.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(window).load(function(){
              
            var table = $('table');
            
            $('#column-1, #column-2, #column-3, #column-4, #column-5, #column-6')
                .wrapInner('<span title="Sort this column"/>')
                .each(function(){
                    
                    var th = $(this),
                        thIndex = th.index(),
                        inverse = false;
                    
                    th.click(function(){
                        
                        table.find('td').filter(function(){
                            
                            return $(this).index() === thIndex;
                            
                        }).sortElements(function(a, b){
                            
                            return $.text([a]) > $.text([b]) ?
                                inverse ? -1 : 1
                                : inverse ? 1 : -1;
                            
                        }, function(){
                            
                            // parentNode is the element we want to move
                            return this.parentNode; 
                        });
                        
                        inverse = !inverse;
                    });
                });
            });

        </script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <xsl:variable name="PubDB" select="document('MSA_PublisherDatabase.XML')"/>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <th class="cellSortHeading" id="column-1">Student</th>
            <th class="cellSortHeading" id="column-2">Last As Student</th>
            <th class="cellSortHeading" id="column-3">Last Bible Reading</th>
            <th class="cellSortHeading" id="column-4">Last As Publisher</th>
            <th class="cellSortHeading" id="column-5">Last As Talk</th>
            <th class="cellSortHeading" id="column-6">Last As Assistant</th>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$PubDB/msa:PublisherDatabase/msa:Publishers/msa:Publisher">
              <xsl:sort select="msa:Name" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="msa:Publisher">
    <xsl:variable name="HistoryDB" select="document('AssignHistory.XML')"/>
    <xsl:variable name ="SearchName" select="msa:Name"/>
    <tr>
      <!--The first cell is the name-->
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="msa:Name"/>
      </td>
      <!--The next cell is the most recent Student date-->
      <!--So we need to locate all "Bible Reading" items for the name in question-->
      <!--We sort the entries in date descending order so that the first entry is the most recent-->
      <td>
        <xsl:for-each select="$HistoryDB/AssignmentHistory/*/StudentItems/Item[Description != 'Assistant' and Name = $SearchName]">
          <xsl:sort select="$HistoryDB/AssignmentHistory/*" order="descending" data-type="text"/>
          <!--We only want the first entry-->
          <xsl:if test="position()=1">
            <xsl:call-template name="DisplayItemDate">
              <xsl:with-param name="ItemDate" select="name(../..)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <!--If no entries were found then it need to write out "<xsl:text> </xsl:text>" How?-->
      </td>
      <!--The next cell is the most recent Bible Reading date-->
      <!--So we need to locate all "Bible Reading" items for the name in question-->
      <!--We sort the entries in date descending order so that the first entry is the most recent-->
      <td>
        <xsl:for-each select="$HistoryDB/AssignmentHistory/*/StudentItems/Item[Description = 'Bible Reading' and Name = $SearchName]">
          <xsl:sort select="$HistoryDB/AssignmentHistory/*" order="descending" data-type="text"/>
          <!--We only want the first entry-->
          <xsl:if test="position()=1">
            <xsl:call-template name="DisplayItemDate">
              <xsl:with-param name="ItemDate" select="name(../..)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <!--If no entries were found then it need to write out "<xsl:text> </xsl:text>" How?-->
      </td>
      <!--The next cell is the most recent Publisher date-->
      <!--So we need to locate all "Bible Reading" items for the name in question-->
      <!--We sort the entries in date descending order so that the first entry is the most recent-->
      <td>
        <xsl:for-each select="$HistoryDB/AssignmentHistory/*/StudentItems/Item[Description != 'Talk' and Description != 'Assistant' and Name = $SearchName]">
          <xsl:sort select="$HistoryDB/AssignmentHistory/*" order="descending" data-type="text"/>
          <!--We only want the first entry-->
          <xsl:if test="position()=1">
            <xsl:call-template name="DisplayItemDate">
              <xsl:with-param name="ItemDate" select="name(../..)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <!--If no entries were found then it need to write out "<xsl:text> </xsl:text>" How?-->
      </td>
      <!--The next cell is the most recent Talk date-->
      <!--So we need to locate all "Bible Reading" items for the name in question-->
      <!--We sort the entries in date descending order so that the first entry is the most recent-->
      <td>
        <xsl:for-each select="$HistoryDB/AssignmentHistory/*/StudentItems/Item[Description = 'Talk' and Name = $SearchName]">
          <xsl:sort select="$HistoryDB/AssignmentHistory/*" order="descending" data-type="text"/>
          <!--We only want the first entry-->
          <xsl:if test="position()=1">
            <xsl:call-template name="DisplayItemDate">
              <xsl:with-param name="ItemDate" select="name(../..)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <!--If no entries were found then it need to write out "<xsl:text> </xsl:text>" How?-->
      </td>
      <!--The last cell is the most recent Assistant date-->
      <!--So we need to locate all "Bible Reading" items for the name in question-->
      <!--We sort the entries in date descending order so that the first entry is the most recent-->
      <td>
        <xsl:for-each select="$HistoryDB/AssignmentHistory/*/StudentItems/Item[Type = 'Assistant' and Name = $SearchName]">
          <xsl:sort select="$HistoryDB/AssignmentHistory/*" order="descending" data-type="text"/>
          <!--We only want the first entry-->
          <xsl:if test="position()=1">
            <xsl:call-template name="DisplayItemDate">
              <xsl:with-param name="ItemDate" select="name(../..)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <!--If no entries were found then it need to write out "<xsl:text> </xsl:text>" How?-->
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="DisplayItemDate">
    <xsl:param name="ItemDate"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring($ItemDate, 8, 2)"/>
    <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring($ItemDate, 6, 2)"/>
    <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring($ItemDate, 2, 4)"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It worked when I viewed it with a "local web server" but not from within CHtmlView. So at the moment I think I go revert back to trying to get the XSL itself to sort on any column if at all possible.

Comment: I have come to the conclusion that it is not possible to do this kind of sorting "after the event". Since it does not have the data in the table until it has built it.

Comment: Is it possible for you to share sample data from the 2 XMLs being used?

Comment: @AniketV I could, but up until now I have not seen any way to combine the results from several `for-each` loops and then sort the whole lot based on any column.